# How do I determine if a document is an article?

Tags: parsing, solr, filtering, apache-tika

Say I've X documents what algorithm/library/tika config/nekohtml filter would tell me which of those is an "article" and which is not, and for those that are give me the article text (i.e. w/o other surrounding text).

By an article I mean a chunck of structured text comprosing at least one paragraph, and I think most human readers can filter those out.

The easiest way I thought of is ensuring that doclength > Y, where Y would be 350 words for example.
But that's not the most reliable of ways, since there could be very long lists for example, and it doesn't give me the article text.
Looking for

tags, is not good enough.

Comment: I am not sure there is any generally accepted definition of what constitutes an article; nor that most human readers could filter them out. What, in your view, constitutes an article - ie what are the criteria you would apply to differentiate an article from another piece of text.

Comment: @Chris: I think any human can tell what I'm looking for. Lenght and structure are the main discriminants here. Say a library that could tell complete English sentences would be in the right direction. It would be returning as an article all text from the first complete sentence until an incomplete sentence is found. An article with sub-headings would be parsed as multiple articles, but that's okay -> Composite Pattern

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can user [Boilerpipe](http://code.google.com/p/boilerpipe/) to extract the text from the page and then decide yourself if it's an article based on your heuristics, i.e. article length. I'm afraid though that your solution would not work anyway. A list of disconnected items still look like a list of sentences. You'd need to "understand" the content.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on factors like throughput, latency, connectivity, and other non-technical factors such as money, if it's something that humans can easily do but hard for computers, you might want to consider using [Amazon Mechanical Turk](http://aws.amazon.com/mturk/) to define HITs to tell an article from other kinds of text. There's an [API](http://aws.amazon.com/code/Amazon-Mechanical-Turk?browse=1) to integrate HIT results with your code.